# ActiveRecord get all Post inside array of categories with all their categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have two models like this:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
wns
```

I'm trying to get all posts that are inside an array of categories:

```
Post.includes(:categories).where(categories: { name: current_user['categories'] })
```

The problem with this is when a Post has several categories, those aren't included. Only categories that are explicitly mentioned inside `current_user['categories']` are returned for each post.

Basically if I'm searching for all posts inside category A and B `current_user['categories'] = ['A','B']`, if a post belongs to categories A and C, my query will return only category A. I want post to return category A AND C.

Comment: It can be done with joins.. what you have right now will not get you the data as you need.. I'll answer it if it remains unanswered..

Comment: Is it `has_many :through` Association? How do you need to access and show category `C`? If posts with category C have intersection with post of category D, what do do? I suggest to current user category as array of ids. Can you post your models and associations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about this one ? or there is another table between posts & categories

```
post_ids = Category.where(name: current_user['categories']).collect(&:post_id).uniq
```

also you can use much better pluck too

```
post_ids =  Category.where(name: current_user['categories']).pluck("distinct post_id")

Post.includes(:categories).where(id: post_ids)
```

Comment: You can write it as `Category.where(name: current_user['categories']).pluck("distinct post_id")`

Comment: Yup thanks... Will change to pluck. I am used to collect always :) also i avoid using SQL literals

Comment: There's a many to many relation between Post and Category though, category doesn't have a post_id colmn

Comment: then how Post and categories are related. you have an intermediate table ?

Comment: please put all the models. so that we can help much better. I feel you have category in between Categories and Product

Comment: Hey you're right my post wasn't very clear. I updated it, hope it's better?

Comment: Found it, you weren't far off: `post_ids = Post.includes(:categories).where(categories: { name: current_user['categories'] }).pluck('id')`. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: But you dont need to make post_ids unique. It has no effect on the next query.